# select 2nd LI that contains specific class name and show it

Tags: jquery, bxslider

using BXSlider and trying to sort the bug about last slide being shown first on slideshow.

What I want to be able to do is find the 2nd instance of ul.bxslider li.bx-clone in the code and show it.

So bassically we have:

```
<li class="All bx-clone" style="display: none; float: left; list-style: none outside none; position: relative; width: 980px;"></li>
<li class="All " style="display: block; float: left; list-style: none outside none; position: relative; width: 980px;"></li>
<li class="All " style="display: block; float: left; list-style: none outside none; position: relative; width: 980px;"></li>
<li class="All bx-clone" style="display: none; float: left; list-style: none outside none; position: relative; width: 980px;"></li>
```

Any ideas what jQuery would do this?

e.g. so that the last LI can have display:block applied?

Comment: use [`nth-child`](http://devdocs.io/css/:nth-child)

Comment: Good plan - used last-child CSS

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has the [`.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method that allow you to select an element into the jQuery stack :

```
$('ul.bxslider li.bx-clone').eq(1 /*0 based index*/).show();
```